# Need help interpreting log file and installing missing AMD driver dependencies

Tags: drivers, ati, fglrx, log

I'm having trouble installing the [AMD Catalyst 14.6 Beta Driver for Linux](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx) on my Ubuntu Gnome 14.04. I know this might seem trivial but I need help interpreting and understanding the names and installation order of the missing dependencies. Here's how the fglrx-install.log looks like:

```
NOTE: If your system has logged the missing packages required for installation, install them in the order as per the log file to resolve package-dependency issues.
Package build failed!
Package build utility output:
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 294: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: debclean: not found
dpkg-buildpackage: source package fglrx-installer
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2:14.200-0ubuntu1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution trusty
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by AMD: Advanced Micro Devices. <http://ati.amd.com/support/driver.html>
 dpkg-source --before-build fglrx.8ubA98
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 debian/rules build
#Create important strings
for i in 10fglrx \
                         dkms.conf \
                         fglrx.install \
                         fglrx-dev.install \
                         fglrx-dev.links \
                         fglrx-amdcccle.install \
                         fglrx.grub-gfxpayload \
                         fglrx.dirs \
                         fglrx.links \
                         fglrx.postinst \
                         fglrx.postrm \
                         fglrx.preinst \
                         fglrx.prerm \
                         overrides/fglrx; do \
                sed -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
                        -e "s|#LIBDIR#|usr/lib|g" \
                        -e "s|#LIBDIR32#|usr/lib32|g" \
                        -e "s|#BINDIR#|usr/bin|g" \
                        -e "s|#SYSCONFDIR#|etc|g" \
                        -e "s|#MANDIR#|usr/share/man/man1|g" \
                        -e "s|#LDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf|g" \
                        -e "s|#ALTLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf|g" \
                        -e "s|#ALTPRIORITY#|1000|g" \
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

First line of output logged by installer said `debclean: not found`

You need to install the following packages in order to build your drivers :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs dh-make dkms execstack dh-modaliases fakeroot libqtgui4
```